# aiohttp has different response to http.client in Python request to API

Tags: python, aiohttp

**Context:**

This works:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("something-api.com")
payload = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=123-123-123&client_secret=123123&scope=something something'
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
conn.request("POST", "/connect/token", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

This does not. It returns `{ 'error':'invalid_client' }`.

```
async def get_token(self):
    params = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": "123-123-123",
        "client_secret": "123123",
        "scope": "something something"
    }

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }
    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with await session.post(
                url="https://something-api.com/connect/token",
                params=params,
                headers=headers) as response:
            return await response.json()

async def authorise(self):
    response = await self.get_token()
    # Returns { 'error':'invalid_client' }
    return response

# -- Just so you can see how it's called:
authorise_task: tasks.Task = asyncio.create_task(example.authorise())
access_token = await authorise_task
```

**Question:**

I cannot understand what the difference is between them. Any ideas what might be happening?

**I've also tried:**

- Adding headers to the `ClientSession(headers=headers)` too.
- Using the URL and removing params

**Other notes:**

- aiohttp docs here: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html
- aiohttp version: `3.7.4.post0`

Comment: try this: replace the arg's name `params` to `data` or `json`. `params` is for url query args like "/?a=1&b=2". Post body use data or json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in docs:

#### for GET query

```
params –

Mapping, iterable of tuple of key/value pairs or string to be sent as parameters in the query string of the new request. Ignored for subsequent redirected requests (optional)

Allowed values are:

collections.abc.Mapping e.g. dict, aiohttp.MultiDict or aiohttp.MultiDictProxy

collections.abc.Iterable e.g. tuple or list

str with preferably url-encoded content (Warning: content will not be encoded by aiohttp)
```

#### for POST body

```
data – The data to send in the body of the request. This can be a FormData object or anything that can be passed into FormData, e.g. a dictionary, bytes, or file-like object. (optional)
```

```
json – Any json compatible python object (optional). json and data parameters could not be used at the same time.
```

Comment: Trock. This works. Thank you. I'm a little confused as I thought this should go through as part of the URL. So thank you so much for that info! "data" worked